# display custom block in product detail page content magento?

Tags: magento, product, static-block

I need to add static block between media and product-description-tabs .

I have set in product edit under design tab "Custom Layout Update"

```
  <reference name="product.info">
 <block type="cms/block" name="my_custom_block" before="-">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>my_custom_block</block_id></action>
  </block>
 </reference>
```

but block is not displaying.
can anyone plz help me

Comment: What happens if you place somewhere this code `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my_custom_block') ?>` in the file catalog/product/view.phtml of your current theme?

Answer (score 1):

I placed this in my home.phtml

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_featured')->setTemplate('catalog/product/featured.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your view.phtml:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my_custom_block');
echo $block->toHtml();
```

Does it display your blocks content?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Step 1:
Create your static block in the admin area of Magento. (CMS > Static Blocks) Click on ‘+ Add New Block’. The ‘Identifier’ is what you’ll need to take note of for embedding the block.

Step 2:
Navigate your way to the layout folder. (app > design > frontend > default > your_theme > layout) Open the file that references the page you intend to put the block into. In my case ‘page.xml’.

Step 3:
Find the spot in the .xml where you would like your block to appear and insert the following code where xxxxxx is the ‘Identifier’ you set earlier when creating your block.

```
<block type="cms/block" name="xxxxxx">  
  <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>;xxxxxx</block_id></action>  
</block>
```

Step 4:
Navigate your way to the template folder (app > design > frontend > default > your_theme > template) Open the file that you would like the block to appear in and insert the following code in the appropriate position where xxxxxx is the ‘Identifier’ you set earlier when creating your block.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('xxxxxx') ?>
```

OR

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock(’cms/block’)->setBlockId(’my-new-block’)->toHtml() ?>
```

OR

```
getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_related')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/related.phtml')->toHtml() ;
?>
```

OR

check following link

http://www.phptechi.com/how-to-add-static-block-in-magento.html

I hope this will help you :)